# How to use the Type argument in JsonSerializer?

Tags: java, json, gson

There are many examples on the web of how to do custom serialization/deserialization in Java using Gson (e.g., [Java Creed](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-serialiser-example/) has a nice tutorial).  What I haven't found, and what I don't understand, is how I'm supposed to use the second `Type` argument of the [JsonSerializer#serialize(T, Type, JsonSerializationContext)](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html#serialize(T,%20java.lang.reflect.Type,%20com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext)) method.

Is it just for type-checking in my implementation?  Can someone provide an illustrative example?

Answer (score 1):

It could be used to test the class of the object using equality rather than instanceof, since Class implements the Type interface.

Here's a working example using a registerTypeHierarchyAdapter() with a serializer that behaves differently depending on the type argument.

```
public static class Animal { }
public static class Horse extends Animal {}
public static class Sheep extends Animal {}

private static class MySerializer implements JsonSerializer<Animal> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Animal src, Type typeOfSrc,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonPrimitive element = null;
        if (typeOfSrc == Sheep.class) {
            element = new JsonPrimitive("sheep");
        } else if (typeOfSrc == Horse.class) {
            element = new JsonPrimitive("horse");
        }
        return element; 
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Animal.class, new MySerializer());
    System.out.println(builder.create().toJson(
            Arrays.asList(new Horse(), new Sheep())));
}
```

This should be equivalent to

```
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Animal src, Type typeOfSrc,
            JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonPrimitive element = null;
        if (src instanceof Sheep) {
            element = new JsonPrimitive("sheep");
        } else if (src instanceof Horse) {
            element = new JsonPrimitive("horse");
        }
        return element; 
    }
```

The differences between using src and typeOfSrc appear to be subtle and I'm still researching. java.lang.Type is the super interface for all types. So there may be some corner case where you can do something with Type you can't do without Class.

```
java.lang.reflect.Type
  => java.lang.Class
  => GenericArrayType
  => ParameterizedType
  => TypeVariable
  => etc.
```

Comment: Adam, thank for you the awesome example!  I guess my follow up question is why use `typeOfSrc == Sheep.class` instead of `src instanceof Sheep`?  In the latter case I am still not making use of the `typeOfSrc`.